# Configurating push notifications

Tags: push-notifications

I've been struggling for a while with push notifications. I want to configure them so I can avoid getting social networking notifications while at work. I don't want to uninstall them or log out, and I don't want to receive them while at work, as I am easily distracted by them and don't get anything done (but I do want to receive them after 7 pm)

I'd also like to still receive my mail and other notifications normally, I just want to "remove" some of them.
out, and I don't want to receive them while at work (but I do want to receive them after 7 pm)

Is there any solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what your problem is, but on Android 5 you can categorize your notifications to normal or high priority. Instead of setting your phone to vibrate you can now set Android to show "All", "Only high priority" or "None" notifications. 
See this link for additional info: https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6111295?hl=en

Comment: I simply want a way to not get social networking notifications while at work, and receive them all at the end of the day.

Comment: Sadly that is not possible. but with my suggestions, at least your phone won't disturb you with new social networking notifications, but if you turn the screen on they are present.